# Running Firefox on geckodriver 0.23 and Firefox 57 on Robot 3.1 and Python 3.7, 32 bit

Tags: firefox, robotframework, geckodriver

I am trying to run Robot code on Firefox browser.
My setup is:

- Selenium version is 3.141,
- Robot version is 3.1,
- Python version is 3.7,
- Selenium library version is 3.3,
- Gecko driver version is 0.23

This is my keyword.

```
Setup Browser Firefox
    ${caps}    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].common.desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX    sys,selenium.webdriver
    Set To Dictionary    ${caps}    marionette=${True}
    Set Global Variable    ${GLOBAL_SELENIUM_BROWSER_CAPABILITIES}   ${caps} 
    Create Webdriver    Firefox .
    Go To  www.google.com
```

Every time I run the code, I get the error

> keyError=sessionId

I have tried it with other combinations of geckodriver and Firefox, too, but without success.

Note: please ignore indentation.